# Decrypt selective parts of AES encrypted files

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a few large encrypted files using code from https://gist.github.com/hanswolff/8809275.

This is the encryption code:

```
BUF_LENGTH = 16
FileStream FsInput = new FileStream(InFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
FileStream FsOutput = new FileStream(OutFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
byte[] ReadBuffer = new byte[BUF_LENGTH];
long InFileLength = FsInput.Length;
long AllBytes = 0;
int PartBytes = 0;

if (InFileLength == 0)
    return false;

ICryptoTransform AESEncryptor = AESEncoder.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, null);
CrStream = new CryptoStream(FsOutput, AESEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

while (AllBytes < InFileLength)
{
    PartBytes = FsInput.Read(ReadBuffer, 0, BUF_LENGTH);
    CrStream.Write(ReadBuffer, 0, PartBytes);
    AllBytes = AllBytes + PartBytes;
}
CrStream.Close();
FsInput.Close();
FsOutput.Flush();
FsOutput.Close();
```

The code works nicely for complete files.
What want is to selectively seek to a specific block of an encrypted file and decrypt only that block.

Guess this is possible?
[CipherInputStream](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/582d926fbf5f5fd4800def67f86ecfedee44681e/crypto/src/main/java/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.java) seems to do the job, but I need this done in C#.

```
private byte[] read_block(String filepath, long pos, int length)
{
    byte[] data = readfile(filepath, pos, length); // returns the specific block.
    byte[] plaindata = new byte[data.Length];

    byte[] kb = PrepareKeyIvBytes();
    byte[] nba = new byte[IvBytes.Length];
    IvBytes.CopyTo(nba, 0);
    AESDecoder = new Aes128CounterMode(nba);
    ICryptoTransform AESDecryptor = AESDecoder.CreateDecryptor(IvBytes, null);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    CrStream = new CryptoStream(ms, AESDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    CrStream.Write(data, 0, length);
    CrStream.Close();
    ms.Flush();

    ms.ToArray().CopyTo(plaindata, 0);
    return plaindata;
}
```

I wrote this piece of code, but it only works as long as we keep the `pos` variable to 0. If I set it to some other value like 512, it doesn't work.
Anybody knows where I should look?
Thanks!

Comment: Because. you also need to set the counter to pos for the CTR mode. IV+pos

Comment: I think Hans Wolff considered this part in his code. Could you please verify here: https://gist.github.com/hanswolff/8809275 ?

Comment: I think you can use his `IncrementCounter` function, that will all you need.

Comment: Thanks! it worked!

Comment: Post it as an answer. I'll upvote.

Comment: When you post the answer let me know.